# Celery: ensure tasks are executed sequentially

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, celery

In a project I'm currently working on, I issue Celery tasks every once in a while. These tasks are for specific clients, so there are tasks for e.g. clientA, for clientB and for clientC. There are some additional conditions:

- Tasks for the same client may never be executed in parallel.
- Tasks for the same client must be executed in sequence, i.e. message queue order.

The [Celery cookbook](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time) (see also [this article](http://loose-bits.com/2010/10/distributed-task-locking-in-celery.html)) shows a locking mechanism that ensures that a single task can only be executed one at a time. This mechanism could easily be adapted to ensure that a task for a single client could only be executed one at a time. This satisfies the first condition.

The second condition is harder to ensure. Since tasks are generated from different processes, I can't use task chaining. Perhaps I could modify the locking mechanism to retry tasks while they are waiting for the lock, but this still can not guarantee order (due to retry timeouts, but also due to a race condition in acquiring the lock.)

For now, i have limited my concurrency to 1 to ensure order, although some of the tasks are taking a long time and this scales quite badly.